# Inserting a Datetime value into SQL Server CE in Webmatrix 3

Tags: datetime, insert, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I want to insert a `datetime` value into a database using SQL Server Compact Edition in Microsoft Webmatrix 3.

I tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Tutorials ([Tutorial], [StartDate]) 
VALUES ('3d', CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-23-08', 110));
```

And I got the following error message:

> The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = datetime, Type to convert to (if known) = float ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
INSERT INTO Tutorials ([Tutorial], [StartDate]) 
VALUES ('3d', CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-23-08', 10));
```

If you set the style value to 10 the input format must be `mm-dd-yy`, if you add 100 to the style value the expected format has a four digit year (`110` --> `mm-dd-yyyy`).

For an exhaustive table of the style values look at [CAST and CONVERT (SQL Server Compact)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx).

By the way, you could take advantage of an implicit conversion using a date format like `yyyymmdd` or `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
INSERT INTO Tutorials ([Tutorial], [StartDate]) 
VALUES ('3d', '20080723');
```